# Invoke Method Using Custom Annotation - JAVA

Tags: java, annotations, aop, aspectj, dropwizard

I'm building a generic exception handler in dropwizard. I want to provide custom annotation as part of library, which will invoke a handleException method whenever exception is raised in method(method that contains annotation)

Details:
Custom annotation is `@ExceptionHandler`

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ExceptionHandler{
    Class<? extends Throwable>[] exception() default {};
}
```

There is a handler method `handleException(Exception, Request)` in class `ExceptionHandlerImpl`.

Now there's a business class that has method with annotation

```
@ExceptionHandler(exception = {EXC1,EXC2})
Response doPerformOperation(Request) throws EXC1,EXC2,EXC3{}
```

Now whenever `EXC1` and `EXC2` are raised by method `doPerformOperation`, I want to invoke `handleException` method.

I tried reading about AOP(AspectJ), Reflection, but not able to figure out the best optimal way to perform this.

Comment: Should the exception just be logged and escalated up the callstack anyway or do you expect the exception to be caught and the problem "repaired"? I am asking because if you want to repair it you need to generate a `Response` to be returned by your method. The solution I may suggest depends on your answer.

Comment: Would it be more sensible to standard JAX-RS exception mappers (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6653) and provide exception handlers depending on the exception type?

Comment: @kriegaex : I do not need any return value. I've solved the problem using aspectjrt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this using aspectj. I have created interface

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface HandleExceptionSet {
    HandleException[] exceptionSet();
}
```

Where HandleException is another annotation. This is to allow array of exceptions.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
public @interface HandleException {
    Class<? extends CustomException> exception() default CustomException.class;
}
```

Now I have a ExceptionHandler class, which has handler. To bind a method to this annotation, I'm using below configuration in module.

```
bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(HandleExceptionSet.class), new ExceptionHandler());
```

I use this annotation in classes, with below snippet.

```
@HandleExceptionSet(exceptionSet = {
        @HandleException(exception = ArithmeticException.class),
        @HandleException(exception = NullPointerException.class),
        @HandleException(exception = EntityNotFoundException.class)
})
public void method()throws Throwable {
    throw new EntityNotFoundException("EVENT1", "ERR1", "Entity Not Found", "Right", "Wrong");
}
```

This is working for me right now. 
Not sure, if this is the best approach.

Is there any better way to achieve this?